# Wife asking her husband forcefully to give her Talaq with some fake stories and witnessess

Tags: fiqh, talaq, husband-wife

I have married past 6-7 months past, but with the passing time she started to fight with every now and then and told me that I am poor and not cant give her a wealthy life and my house is too small etc etc comparing my earnings to that of her father ( he is financially sound ). coming past 2 months she's gone to her Mother's house and said me that she will not return to me as I am not wealthy, I am behaving like paranoid & so on. When I tried to convince her she in back gifted me with bad words in foul language and her parents are fully in her support.

Lastly she has applied to their Muslim Masjid Jamat and lodged complaint saying that I am Unfit for her in any terms and I uttered her Talaq in phone for 2 times and as now she says that our relation is Haram and she could not be with me any more. Jamat gave 1 month time for me to try her to convince her and save my relation but she and her family are continuously saying that this relation is Haram.

Now in next 2 days two months will complete as she left me and after coming 12 days the Jamat given time will also get completed but the same story that our relation is haram is going on, but I am trying my day and night to convince her but its of nil results as she is not even ready to hear me.She keeps on blaming me that I am not a responsible man. Allah knows the best what is true.

Answer (score 1):

The self respect taught in Islam teaches us that if a woman asks to be divorced or asks for khulla one should not delay in doing so. 
In this case you should let her go. Not at all because her complains are true or not but because she has by word and action shown that she has no wish to remain your wife. 
Do istikhara. Be patient. If she is gone let her go with a gift.

Answer (score 0):

Khula’ means the separation of the wife in return for a payment; the husband takes the payment and lets his wife go [[islamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/26247)]

Wife is allowed to ask for *khula* when the husband ***fails*** to provide her with necessary food, clothing or accommodation [[IslamToday](http://en.islamtoday.net/print/1110)]. Further examples of acceptable reasons for asking one’s husband for khula’ can be found [here](https://islamqa.info/en/1859).

That was all about literature on khula'. However, according to your explanation, there seems to be no valid reason with her to ask for divorce. It has been said that a woman who asks divorce without sound reason is denied *the fragrance of paradise*. [[islamtoday](http://en.islamtoday.net/print/1103)].

Allah knows best what is in her heart. Either way, if she is determined to separate, she has the legal right to do so, as [this fatwa](http://en.islamtoday.net/print/1110) says:

- *if the husband did not do any harm to his wife and the woman wants the divorce for any other reason than those we already mentioned, then the husband should still willingly divorce her, and he will be rewarded for that, but if he refuses, she can redeem herself.*

Lastly, due to khula, the husband is [entitled to compensation](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=276691), however, the amount must not be more than mahr.